# How can I return to command line with jupyter notebook running?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I am connected to a Linode terminal via SSH. 
I have started a Jupyter Notebook server from the command line. 
But I want to do some other tasks in the command line, keeping the NB server running. I can't work out how to do this without stopping the Jupyter Notebook server. It says:

```
[I 05:55:05.523 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut 
down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
```

Comment: Why cant to craete a new SSH-session and thereby get a new terminal?

Comment: Yes, a new Cygwin window is the only solution I found. I just thought it surprising that by default it doesn't run a daemon in the background  when you start notebook in a terminal session

Answer (score 2):

Since you mentioned Linode, I'm assuming it is on a linux/unix system.

Possbile options:

1. Send process to background

   1. send process to background: `jupyter notebook &`
   2. do some work on terminal
   3. close jupyter with `pkill jupyter` (this should have the same effect as 
      a ctrl+c keypress)

      - **WARNING**: this will kill **all** jupyter instances
2. use a terminal multiplexer like tmux
3. just use multiple ssh sessions (not really elegant imo)

Overall, I think the option that would be easiest and most flexible is option 2.